# synchronized this vs field in Java

Tags: java, synchronization, locks

```
class BankAccount {
  private int balance = 0;

  int getBalance() {
    synchronized(this) {
      return balance;
    }
  }

  void setBalance(int x) {
    synchronized(this) {
      balance = x;
    }
  }

  void withdraw(int amount) {
    synchronized(this) {
      int b = getBalance();
      if (amount > b)
        throw...
          setBalance(b– amount);
    }
  }
}
```

In withdraw there is "synchronized (this) ...".

Let's say I have in another method "synchronized (balance) ..." (so a lock on balance and not on "this"), can that method be executed at the same moment withdraw is executed?

Comment: I have formatted your code for readability, but this is something you should really be doing yourself

Comment: Try writing `synchronized(balance)`. What does the compiler say? Why?

Comment: Try setting up a little program with a couple of threads and some `Thread.sleep` calls, so that you can check these things yourself.

Comment: "so a lock on balance and not on "this"" what are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Comment: `synchronized(this) {` is essentially doing the same thing as `synchronized void withdraw(int amount) {` (in the context of this example), so it's locking on the instance of the object.  The use of `synchronized` should focus on critical paths, so two threads can't modify the balance at the same time, for example.  The next question is why would you want to lock on `balance` (assuming you actually could) over `this` in this case?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I still don't fully understand it. "synchronized (balance) ..." puts a lock on balance, which is not the same as putting a lock on the instance? This means that a synchronized method (i.e., a method with body "synchronized (this) ...")  can still be executed at the same time "synchronized (balance) ..." is executed?

Comment: `synchronized (balance)` (assuming you could) would lock any other parts of your code which used the same thing, so if you did it in withdraw and deposit, only one thread would be able to execute those critical paths at a time - but, `synchronized` works on `Object`s only. `synchronized (this)` is locking on the instance object itself - so it's a matter of need/desire and the level of granularity you need. Also remember, you could do `synchronized (instanceOfBankAccount) { ...}` and this would also prevent any other threads from been able to execute the (`synchronized(this)`) critical paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question.

> *"... Let's say I have in another method "synchronized (balance) ..." (so a lock on balance and not on "this"), can that method be executed at the same moment withdraw is executed?"*

This is the exact reason there are both *synchronized methods* and *synchronized statements*.
You can fine tune the synchronization, as to prevent unnecessary blocking within threads.

All synchronization does is allow for only one thread to execute the code-block at a time.

So, if you are using *synchronized(this)*, then the entire instance will block other threads, on any invocation.
Whereas, if you are synchronizing on just a single variable, then only invocations on that object—or variable—will block.

*[Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization (The Java™ Tutorials > Essential Java Classes > Concurrency)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)*.

Here is a relevant excerpt.

> *"... Synchronized statements are also useful for improving concurrency with fine-grained synchronization. Suppose, for example, class MsLunch has two instance fields, c1 and c2, that are never used together. All updates of these fields must be synchronized, but there's no reason to prevent an update of c1 from being interleaved with an update of c2 — and doing so reduces concurrency by creating unnecessary blocking. Instead of using synchronized methods or otherwise using the lock associated with this, we create two objects solely to provide locks. ..."*

Comment: Thank you! "So, if you are using synchronized(this), then the entire instance will block other threads, on any invocation." So even invocations of methods that are not synchronized? can you provide sources that confirm this statement?

Comment: @Ronald, correct.  The lock will be on _this_, the instance, thus any thread which is encountering the same instance, will be blocked, until the synchronized code-block is exited.  The following tutorial explains it, under the area titled, "Synchronized Statements", in bold. 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html.

Comment: thanks! so the answer of Arfur Narf is actually wrong?

Comment: and I don't see it directly mentioned in the source?

Comment: @Ronald, no, they are still correct.  I believe you're interpreting it incorrectly.  Imagine you have a one _new BankAccount_ object.  And, you have 2 threads which work simultaneously on that same object.  Providing the _synchronized(this)_ statement, will block the other threads invocations upon the same object, until the accessing thread has completed that code-block.  That user is under the assumption you are referring to two separate instances.  The synchronization is upon the instance, and not the class.  So two separate objects will not be affected by a lock.

Comment: I indeed meant one single instance, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Ronald, sure, no problem.  The concept of threading is very basic, the actual design of the processes can be complex.

Comment: May I ask one final question about this? Let's say I have a private List<Some-Object> objects; and in some method A I have synchronized (objects) {...}. Another method reads from the objects list. Can that other read from the list at the same time the method A is executed?

Comment: @Ronald, yes, if the synchronization is upon _objects_, then that object will only allow for one thread to access it at a time.  On that note, the _Collections_ framework offers an optimized, synchronized _List_, object, via the _[Collections#synchronizedList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List))_ method.

Comment: Thanks. But my question was "Can that other read from the list at the same time the method A is executed?", so the answer to it is "no"? Because you seem to have meant "no"?

Comment: Please note that the other method contains no " synchronized (objects) {...}" blocks. And what would be the difference if it would contain a  synchronized (objects) {...} even though it just reads objects, it doesn't change anything. But I want to prevent race conditions (when method A writes, the other method reads, I want to prevent that).

Comment: @Ronald, my mistake, no it cannot.  I meant, _"yes, it will lock the List object"_.

Comment: @Ronald, the lock is upon any invocation.  So both read and write access.  Essentially, when the thread encounters the object, it's notified that there is a lock, so it just waits.  It cannot even obtain the object.

Comment: @Relias, it's all clear now, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

You can't synchronize on `balance` because it has primitive type: you can only synchronize on non-null reference types.

However, changing `balance` to `Integer` would not be a desirable thing to do: synchronization locks on the expression's value. As such, nothing would stop you doing something like this:

```
// Thread 1.
synchronized (balance) {
  // Do something long-running here.
}

// Thread 2.
balance = balance + 1;
synchronized (balance) {
  // ...
}
```

Nothing stops thread 2 from changing the balance field; and because `(Object) balance != (Object) (balance + 1)` (`!=` meaning "is not the same object as"), thread 2 would then be synchronizing on a different object to thread 1, so there would be no mutual exclusion, happens-before etc.

Not to mention, synchronizing on something as pervasive as an `Integer` could lead to weird behavior, if someone else has access to the same `Integer` (e.g. via autoboxing), and decides to synchronize on it themselves.

Just don't do this: the right thing to synchronize on is the holder of `balance`, i.e. `this`.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm confused. "Nothing stops thread 2 from changing the balance field", but the first thread puts a lock on balance, so balance can't be modified, no?

Comment: so balance = balance + 1 should be possible as long as the synchronized block in thread 1 is running?

Comment: @Ronald no that defeats the synchronization because threads trying to acquire a lock are accessing a different lock than the thread that just changed the balance value. This is totally broken.

Comment: I meant: balance = balance + 1 should NOT be possible as long as the synchronized block in thread 1 is running, right?

Comment: @Ronald no, nothing stops you doing that outside a synchronized block.

Comment: @user16320675 "wouldn't that be even worse than using a private field" it's a question of the value in the private field. If it stores a widely-accessible value (such as a cached Integer), that's worse than using `this`, as I say. If it stores something that is inaccessible outside the object, that's... different. It means that the field value cannot be externally synchronized on, but that doesn't stop somebody externally synchronizing on `this` _in the expectation_ that's the correct thing to do to preserve the internal state. Desirable in some cases, maybe not in others.

Answer (score 1):

> can that method be executed at the same moment withdraw is executed

Ignoring that you can't sync on a primitive `int` and answering as if it were some object type, say `Integer`...

Then, yes, they can execute concurrently, since the two methods are using different locks, and thus neither prevents the other from executing.

It is irrelevant that one of the objects sync'd-on happens to contain the other object being sync'd-on.